# What is the meaning of six-five?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the Battle of Scarif, a pilot shouts out

> More fighters! Form up at six-five!

as imperial fighters are dispatched.

**What is 65? Is that a formation or some sort of coordinates?**

Comment: There's also a callout of "form up at point oh-five" in the Battle of Yavin. I've always assumed those are coordinates of some kind. Not sure how only two numbers work in a three dimensional theater, though.

Comment: @ToddWilcox A set of premapped vectors, assuming a constant speed, would only need two numbers wouldn't they?

Comment: are we assuming this is more coordinates based or a flight formation?

Comment: @Ash Premapped vectors could only need one piece of information to identify them. It could be that one number is like a pre-defined grid - like 1 - 5 is the first row, 6 - 10 is the second, etc. And then the other number is like an altitude band. So "point oh five" could mean "northeast" corner of altitude band 0, or it could mean the dead center or "northwest" corner of altitude band 5. One challenge is it really limits the size of the area you can refer to. How do you go off the grid? Maybe the grid is relative to your capital ship or to the Death Star?

Comment: @ToddWilcox In _The Lost Fleet_ it's relative to the star, you could use anything you know will be there really.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I guess a flat "earth" could exist only at the surface of a three dimensional universe therefore u need only 2 coordinates in Star WarsI guess

Comment: + "three marks at two-ten", "coming in point three five", "turn to point oh-five". I think it could be direction, just like in WW2 - first number is horizontal clock and second number stands for High/Low - vertical clock.